# What is mysql link identifierand what is the importance of it?

Tags: php, mysql

I have search a lot but didn't found the suitable answer for this.

I have used this:

```
  $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
  mysql_select_db('db_name',$con);
```

and I have also used this:

```
  $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
  mysql_select_db('db_name');
```

Both Works For Me..
What is the difference between them and what is pros and cons of these?

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between them and what is pros and cons of these?

Ignoring, for a moment, the whole deprecation thing, the main difference here is in some magic that the `mysql_` family pulls off.

In specific, *all* `mysql_` family functions that take the link identifier (statement handle, database connection resource, whatever you wish to call it) do so *optionally*.  If the parameter is omitted, it will the *last opened* connection.

This is not the case with the procedural version of [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/book.mysqli), even though many of the functions have the same name and purpose.  In fact, the argument order in `mysqli_` always has the connection first instead of last just for this reason.

You should, as best practice, *never* omit the link identifier in `mysql_`.  Then again, as best practice, you shouldn't be *using* `mysql_`.  The official deprecation notice went up in the manual today.

Methods in [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) and mysqli in object-oriented mode also operate without a connection argument, as the connection is the object on which you call methods.

Answer (score 1):

The second option will use the last link opened by mysql_connect.  If none are found it will try to open a connection with no values (which usually fails).  The first option is better if have multiple database connections open and want to specify which one to use.