# What is meant by $non in this php code?

Tags: php, mysql

The following php code is found in a tutorial where it is intended to connect to a database server.

```
<?php
/*connect to mysql database */  
$non=mysql_connect($host,$dbuser,$dbpassword) or die("Can't connect to server");
mysql_select_db($dbase,$non) or die("can't connect to database");   
?>
```

What does "$non" stand for?
How its execution defers from the following one?

```
<?php
/*connect to mysql database */  
mysql_connect($host,$dbuser,$dbpassword) or die("Can't connect to server");
mysql_select_db($dbase) or die("can't connect to database");    
?>
```

Comment: its variabe which store your server connection information

Comment: 1st: **stop using mysql_* methods, they are deprecated and unsafe!**. 2nd: Check the php manual for this sort of information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: `bool mysql_select_db ( string $database_name [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )`

Comment: This question is similar to this one:[What is mysql link identifierand what is the importance of it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890006/what-is-mysql-link-identifierand-what-is-the-importance-of-it)

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of the function mysql_select_db is the `link_identifier`

If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

Answer (score 0):

It is [resource identifier](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) that other mysql function uses to perform operation. You can have multiple connections to db and resource id in this case refers to connection.

You should not use mysql_* functions there are deprecated in php 5.5 and removed in php 7. Use mysqli or PDO instead.